# Equation number is not appeared using align environment

Tags: align

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

I've used the following code to generate a formula with equation number, nevertheless, the equation number is not appeared:

```
\begin{align}
T(n) & \leq 2(c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg( \lfloor n/2 \rfloor )) + n \\
T(n) & \leq 2(cn/2) \lg(n/2) + n \\
T(n) & = cn (\lg n - 1) + n \\
T(n) & \leq cn \lg n
\end{align}
```

The packages used are as above.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The culprit is found if I put the following line that uses indent command before invoking align command:

```
\indent $ratio_{actual}$ = ground truth ratio between width and length of the box \nonumber \\
```

I'm still curious how I would still use the align command while preserving the indent command.

Comment: No problems here, assuming the `article` class.

Comment: it'd be great if you could make your snippets into a complete MWE - not only will it help the community, but it will also help *you* to diagnose the problem :)

Comment: Did you try using `align` or `aligned` inside `equation` environment?

Comment: I found the culprit as the above EDIT, but still hunting for the remedy.

Comment: @PaulGessler: Yes, it is an article class.

Comment: @cmhughes: I found the culprit.

Comment: @MattAllegro: I try to avoid using equation as the align is normally sufficient.

Comment: @Shah: Why are you using `\noindent...\nonumber\\`? Can you include that in your code? While I can fully reproduce the problem knowing what you wrote, I just don't understand the need for such usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that omitting \nonumber command in the \indent command solves the issue. So, the resultant fix of it is as below:

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage{rotating}

\indent $ratio_{actual}$ = ground truth ratio between width and length of the box \\

\begin{align}
T(n) & \leq 2(c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg( \lfloor n/2 \rfloor )) + n \\
T(n) & \leq 2(cn/2) \lg(n/2) + n \\
T(n) & = cn (\lg n - 1) + n \\
T(n) & \leq cn \lg n
\end{align}
```

Comment: The `\indent` command is doing nothing here (you never need to use `\indent` in LaTeX) Never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph, and never leave a blank line before a math display such as `align`. Also when posting questions and answers please always post complete documents as in Peter's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `\nonumber \\` as I have commented out below you get the numbering:

[image]

### Notes:

- I am not sure what purpose the `\nonumber \\` was to serve.  I don't think there should be a need to use a `\\` outside of a `tabular` or math environment.
- Also, I added a `\mathrm` to the `ratio` and `actual` as I don't think that is more appropriate.
- Have also removed the `\indent` as I am not sure as to why you need it. But, it does not effect the numbering of the `align` environment.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pseudocode}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{ratio}_{\mathrm{actual}}$ = ground truth ratio between width and length of the box  %\nonumber \\
\begin{align}
T(n) & \leq 2(c\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \lg( \lfloor n/2 \rfloor )) + n \\
T(n) & \leq 2(cn/2) \lg(n/2) + n \\
T(n) & = cn (\lg n - 1) + n \\
T(n) & \leq cn \lg n
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, I found another way of resolving it, but this is helpful too.

Comment: @Shah: You should post an answer then. You probably are not the last person to encounter this problem so posting an answer will be helpful.

Comment: I've added but it needs two days for it to be approved. Even so, I'll give a more concrete one. Thanks for reminding me :-)